# Can I fake a storage event in my jasmine unit tests?

Tags: javascript

I'm going to need to handle some storage events.

```
window.addEventListener('storage', listener);
```

I'm trying to unit test my code with jasmine.

Simply putting something into `localStorage` using `setItem(key, value)` in the test won't work since by design the event won't be raised for the originator of the event.

Using `$(window).trigger('storage'...` seemed like a good idea to begin with but I don't think it's right.

I've seen posts asking how to mock local storage with `spyOn` but I can't find any that deal with events.

Comment: why don't you pass a mock `window`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new StorageEvent('storage', {
    key: 'test_key', 
    newValue: 'test_value' 
});
```

For bonus points in IE too:

```
var se = document.createEvent('StorageEvent');
se.initStorageEvent('storage', false, false, 'test_key', null, 'test_value', '/', null);
window.dispatchEvent(se);
```

Comment: Don't forget to also update the local storage itself, if you want to retrieve the value from there instead of the event data; `localStorage.setItem('test_key', 'test_value')`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to put as answer (don't have rep to comment):

I would suggest to start with answering on the question: "What are you trying to test?"

- If you are testing your event handler - call it and provide a mock of event
- If you want to be sure you've attached your handler - spyOn and check that it was attached

As far as I can understand you are writing a unit test - then test your unit and mock all external dependencies. Manually firing events seems more like simulating the browser.

If I'm wrong please explain your situation in more details.

Comment: I'm using localStorage to do messaging, an event will be raised when localStorage is changed from another tab or frame.  I'm not interested in testing that the browser works, I may want to unit test some handling of IE8 storage events but mainly I just want an input to the rest of my code.

Comment: If you have an event handler you can call it manually in the test and provide the event, simple by creating an object with expected structure and values.