# localStorage suddenly broken

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage, redux

EDIT:
Found out it was redux-persist who had breaking changes in a patch revision.

---

I'm developping a webapp in Node, React, Redux, Webpack, etc. One of the packages ([redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)) suddenly throws an error (`Uncaught TypeError: storage.getItem is not a function ( persistStore.js:99`) when rehydrating the state (reading from localStorage).

Hints:

- This problem does not occur on my collegue's environment.
- This happened after trying to update my packages to Babel 6. But I don't see why this would be related.
- I tried `npm cache clean`
- I tried deleting and re-cloning my repo.
- I tried `brew upgrade` and OSX updates (why not anyway!?)
- It happens on **Chrome**, **Safari** which is the first time I opened it, and **Firefox** which I just installed for this purpose.
- I tried `git reset --hard; git clean -xfd; npm install` to a state before ever using redux-persist, and **it didn't throw the error.**

My conclusion is that it is clearly related to my environment, since I can't find anything on this on the web, plus it's not reproducible on my coworker's environment. But I'm out of ideas.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1. Are you using a browser version that supports HTML5 localStorage?

2. Is the call properly scoped (should be as localStorage is part to the window object - unless you are specifically using closures and not passing in the Window reference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in redux-persist@1.5.2 in the way we instantiate the default storage engine.

I just released 1.5.3 which resolves the bug.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is that your browser might be in incognito (private) mode. There is an issue with safari about this, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555347/html5-localstorage-error-with-safari-quota-exceeded-err-dom-exception-22-an).

Comment: redux-persist does a try / catch on the localStorage calls for this reason. If there is an error it does a noop with a warning. Not sure if there is a more elegant way to handle this scenario...