# Do I have access to localStorage in Outlook 2016 desktop client?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office365api

I am building an Office 365 Add-In for Outlook with the 365 javascript API. Can I use `localStorage` in the Outlook 2016 PC client like I can on the Outlook Web App? Or should I use `RoamingSettings`?

It's hard to discern from the docs:
https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can access LocalStorage in your add-in. Indeed, your add-in is a website and in the case of Outlook Desktop the underlying browser is IE. Take care of the case of Safari incognito mode where [localStorage is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555347/html5-localstorage-error-with-safari-quota-exceeded-err-dom-exception-22-an).

RoamingSettings and LocalStorage are different and should be used for different purposes. RoamingSettings is a "per mail account storage" provided by Office.js. LocalStorage is a "per website storage" provided by the browser, precisely, for a given browser and for the same domain you can access the values in LocalStorage.

For example, with RoamingSettings, for a given Microsoft mail account, you can reuse values between your add-in loaded in Office Desktop and in Outlook Online. Of course it can be used only in the context of an add-in.

An example of usage of LocalStorage would be, if you have a web application served with the same domain but which is not the add-in. Then, for the same browser, LocalStorage can be use to share things like token authentication etc.