# Error: The quota has been exceeded. on Safari IOS 10

Tags: javascript, safari, local-storage, ios10

I'm getting this error on my iPhone's safari, when doing `localStorage.setItem('user',`some string here`)`:

> Error: The quota has been exceeded.
>   setItem@[native code]

It is **not private mode**! What other circumstances can make localStorage not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 localStorage error with Safari: "QUOTA\_EXCEEDED\_ERR: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555347/html5-localstorage-error-with-safari-quota-exceeded-err-dom-exception-22-an)

Answer (score 2):

I created this class to help get around private browsing. However, storage will be blown away when you refresh the browser.

```
const data = {};
let hasLocalStorage = false;

if (localStorage) {
  try {
    const x = 'storageTest';
    localStorage.setItem(x, x);
    localStorage.removeItem(x);
    hasLocalStorage = true;
  } catch (e) {
    hasLocalStorage = false;
  }
}

class StorageUtilities {
  setItem(key, value) {
    if (hasLocalStorage) {
      localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    } else {
      data[key] = value;
    }
  }

  getItem(key) {
    if (hasLocalStorage) {
      return localStorage.getItem(key);
    }
    return data[key];
  }

  removeItem(key) {
    if (hasLocalStorage) {
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
    } else {
      data[key] = null;
    }
  }
}

const storageUtilities = new StorageUtilities();

export default storageUtilities;
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. As an addition I would convert the value to String if it is not null at the setItem function to get a more consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was Private mode. Looks like it is enabled by default on new iphones.

Comment: Wait now.  What is this private mode?  I'm just running into this problem where Chrome's working fine but Safari is not and I just figured out how to do Web Inspector from my iPhone.  (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH2-SW2)  But maybe some additional information here would help folks understand why we've got this private mode hurdle to get over and how to avoid it?  I don't want my users having to modify vanilla Safari Mobile settings.

Comment: And thanks Apple for such a useful error message.  :-( Angular and Satellizer both figure it out "o = k(b) || (h.warn("This browser does not support Web Storage!"), {"  But Quota Exceeded?  Really?