# Detect Safari Private Browsing in AppleScript

Tags: cocoa, browser, safari, applescript

I'm trying to write AppleScript which would tell whether **a window of Safari is in private mode**. Here is the AppleScript to do so in Chrome:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set incognitoIsRunning to the (count of (get every window whose mode is "incognito")) is greater than 0
end tell

if (incognitoIsRunning) then
    return "-- PRIVATE MODE --"
end tell
```

The old solution to see whether private browsing menu option is checked no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a quirk in Safari that can be exploited to determine whether private mode is enabled: Safari does not allow localStorage.setItem to be used in private mode (see [related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555347/html5-localstorage-error-with-safari-quota-exceeded-err-dom-exception-22-an)). We can take advantage of this by using a snippet of JavaScript from within AppleScript. If localStorage is not supported, the JavaScript throws an error (caught by the try/catch block), which we use to set our boolean.

```
tell application "Safari"
    set checkMode to "
         var isprivate = false;
          try {
               window.localStorage.setItem('foobar', 1);
          } catch(e) {
               isprivate = true;
          }
       isprivate;
"
    set isPrivate to do JavaScript checkMode in current tab of first window
end tell

log isPrivate
```

Of course you will need to adjust this AppleScript to set the appropriate target window/tab within Safari.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works with Safari 13. (And I believe some earlier versions as well.)

Comment: Unfortunately, not a surprise -- using feature/quirk sniffing is always precarious and will eventually fail when browsers are updated.

Comment: For sure. Especially since browsers actively want to prevent detection of private browsing.