# Applescript to split Safari tabs into new window

Tags: macos, safari, tabs, applescript

I'm trying to write a script that splits the current + all next tabs into a new window — which would be super useful for organization.

It is perfectly possible to get the URLs of the current and all next tabs, make a new window and load all those URLs in new tabs, and then close the tabs in the original window – but that seems very cumbersome and slow.

So, is there any way to **move** a set of Safari tabs to a new window without actually reloading the URLs?

Comment: You can move tabs with the `move` command, for example `move tabs 2 thru 5 of window 1 to window 2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best/right way, but got this working:

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    set original_window to front window
    set tab_index to index of current tab of original_window
    set tab_limit to index of last tab of original_window

    make new document
    move tabs tab_index thru tab_limit of original_window to front window
    close first tab of front window
end tell
```

Comment: You do not need `set tab_limit to index of last tab of original_window`, use `-1` for the last tab, e.g.: `move tabs tab_index thru -1 of original_window to front window`

Comment: Also, this doesn't work with private browsing (it will split tabs from a private window into a regular window). Still figuring that out.

Comment: If the original window is using private browsing then instead of `make new document` use `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {shift down, command down}` to open a new private browsing window.

Comment: Yeah, I've got that part already, but detecting if we're in private browsing isn't that simple. [There was a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182648/detect-safari-private-browsing-in-applescript) but it supposedly no longer works.

Comment: This script does work in Safari 15.5 on Monterey as written in this answer, but the suggestion in comment 1 from @user3439894 does not.

It also will split tabs from a tab group into a new window, but I've not been able to figure out how to split a tab group into another tab group.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a slightly modified version that accounts for pinned tabs, rather than always closing the first tab in the new window:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set original_window to front window
    set current_tab_index to index of current tab of original_window
    set last_tab_index to index of last tab of original_window
    
    make new document
    # Account for pinned tabs; if we assume index 1, we'll close a pinned tab:
    set new_blank_tab to index of last tab of front window
    move tabs current_tab_index thru last_tab_index of original_window to front window
    close tab new_blank_tab of front window
end tell
```