# html storage safari incognito mode, angular2

Tags: javascript, html, ios, angular, safari

I am not able to save any data in HTML local / session storage when safari is in private mode in IOS in iphone 6 plus. Can anyone help me with why this could be happening. Is it possible to over ride it and make it store data?

Comment: any specific error you're getting?

Comment: if you would put in some code and the error that you are getting, it would have been helpful!

Answer (score 2):

possible duplicate : 
[html5 localStorage error with Safari: "QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555347/html5-localstorage-error-with-safari-quota-exceeded-err-dom-exception-22-an).

You can write a script and on exception ask user to open your website in normal mode or in a different browser

```
try {
        localStorage.setItem("check", "test");
        console.log("works!!");
    } catch (exception) {
        console.log('browser / mode not supported');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason is itself the browser, actually, Safari exposes the localStorage object, but it refuses to store any value.

You can store data in cookies instead.