# How to detect private browsing in iOS 11+ Safari as well as older versions of Safari?

Tags: ios, browser, safari, ios11, incognito-mode

I need to detect if user is on private mode in Safari both in older versions as well as Safari on IOS 11. Is there a test that would cover both?

Update: Here is a pen that attempts to combine the storage and openDatabase try-catch blocks based on jeprubio's solution below

```
var isPrivate = false;

// Check private in iOS < 11
var storage = window.sessionStorage;
try {
  console.log('first try for storage')
    storage.setItem("someKeyHere", "test");
    storage.removeItem("someKeyHere");
} catch (e) {
  console.log('first catch')
    if (e.code === DOMException.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR && storage.length === 0) {
        isPrivate = true;
   } 
}

// Check private in iOS 11: https://gist.github.com/cou929/7973956#gistcomment-2272103
try {
  console.log('second try for opendb');
   window.openDatabase(null, null, null, null);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('second catch');
   isPrivate = true;
}

console.log('isPrivate: ' + isPrivate)

alert((isPrivate ? 'You are' : 'You are not')  + ' in private browsing mode');
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpMZjp

In Safari new versions (11+) normal browser mode, that does not error on openDatabase test on the console but enters the second catch and isPrivate gets set to true. So, in Safari 11+ non-private mode is also detected as private mode.

Comment: Why do you want to detect private mode?

Comment: Have a requirement to give users a message that they are on private mode and may experience some limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var isPrivate = false;

// Check private in iOS < 11
var storage = window.sessionStorage;
try {
    storage.setItem("someKeyHere", "test");
    storage.removeItem("someKeyHere");
} catch (e) {
    if (e.code === DOMException.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR && storage.length === 0) {
        isPrivate = true;
   } 
}

// Check private in iOS 11: https://gist.github.com/cou929/7973956#gistcomment-2272103
try {
   window.openDatabase(null, null, null, null);
} catch (_) {
   isPrivate = true;
}

alert((isPrivate ? 'You\'re' : 'You aren\'t')  + ' in private browsing mode');
```

Comment: Seems to be detecting as private mode both for private and non-private modes in latst iOS 11.2.2 Safari.

I used that in this pen so it can be tested quickly.
https://codepen.io/smarajit_dg/pen/oppRaR

Comment: The test

    window.openDatabase(null, null, null, null)
is not expected to throw an exception in Safari non-private browser mode, but it does (exception code 18).

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` doesn't work in private browsing on both macOS and iOS.

If you try `setItem`, it will throw an error. This should allow you to detect private browsing.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14555361/7495369)