# Session Storage Angular 4/5

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, session-storage

How to implement Session storage in this project?:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-material-theming

When I choose the light color and close the browser and return to it - I would like the lightcolor to stay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use LocalStorage. Here is a link to the documentation on it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

One thing it does not mention is the fact that you will run into issues if it is not supported by the [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555347/html5-localstorage-error-with-safari-quota-exceeded-err-dom-exception-22-an). So make sure you handle that situation as well.

```
import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { OverlayContainer} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

const THEME_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'selectedTheme';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  name = 'Angular 5';
  @HostBinding('class') componentCssClass;

  constructor(public overlayContainer: OverlayContainer){
    const theme = localStorage.getItem(THEME_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);      

    if(theme){
      this.onSetTheme(theme);
    }    
  }


  onSetTheme(theme) {
      this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(theme);
      this.componentCssClass = theme;
      localStorage.setItem(THEME_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, theme);      
  }
}
```