# Send message from service woker to react component in some of the browser which donot support BroadcastChannel

Tags: reactjs, web-services, internet-explorer, safari

I am able to successfully get push notification from my server and update react component with this

```
    self.addEventListener('push', event => {
     const data = event.data.json();
     event.waitUntil(
       self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
         body: data.body,
         image: './Flowster-icon-32.png'
      })
    );

     const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages');
     channel.postMessage(data);
   });
```

But browser sucs IE, safari, donto support BroadcastChannel, even client.postMessage is not supported in these browser, how can i make it work in those browser. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [BroadcastChannel doesn't support IE and safari browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=broadcastchannel), as a workaround, I suggest you could try to use the [sysend.js](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js) in IE or safari browser.

Reference: [How can I use the BroadcastChannel API or something similar in Safari 10+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700474/how-can-i-use-the-broadcastchannel-api-or-something-similar-in-safari-10)