# React Getting error with BroadcastChannel API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, broadcast-channel

I am using sessionStorage to keep the auth information and need to replicate this information to other tabs being opened. I have created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dj77b) to recreate the issue. I didn't include code in this post since it is quite lengthy.

When the Dashboard link is opened in another window, it is not rendered due to the error being popped up.

**EDIT:**
I have included all the necessary codes below.

*App.js*

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

*Dashboard.js*

```
export default (props) => {
  const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  const authChannel = new BroadcastChannel("auth");

  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(sessionStorage.getItem("token"));
    setEmail(sessionStorage.getItem("email"));
    setIsLogged(sessionStorage.getItem("token") ? true : false);
    authChannel.postMessage({ action: "created", source: "Dashboard" });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    authChannel.onmessage = function (e) {
      if (
        e.data.action === "login" &&
        (e.data.target === "*" || e.data.target === "Dashboard")
      ) {
        setIsLogged(true);
        setEmail(e.data.data.user.email);
        setToken(e.data.data.token);
        sessionStorage.setItem("email", e.data.data.user.email);
        sessionStorage.setItem("token", e.data.data.token);
      }
    };
  }, [authChannel]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      {isLogged && <h1>You are logged in</h1>}
      {!isLogged && <h1>Please log in</h1>}
    </>
  );
};
```

*Home.js*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default (props) => {
  const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const authChannel = new BroadcastChannel("auth");

  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(sessionStorage.getItem("token"));
    setEmail(sessionStorage.getItem("email"));
    setIsLogged(sessionStorage.getItem("token") ? true : false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    authChannel.onmessage = function (e) {
      if (
        e.data.action === "login" &&
        (e.data.target === "*" || e.data.target === "Home")
      ) {
        setIsLogged(true);
        setEmail(e.data.data.user.email);
        setToken(e.data.data.token);
        setUser(e.data.data.user);
        sessionStorage.setItem("email", e.data.data.user.email);
        sessionStorage.setItem("token", e.data.data.token);
      } else if (e.data.action === "created") {
        authChannel.postMessage({
          action: "login",
          target: e.data.source,
          data: { user: user, token: token }
        });
      }
    };
  }, [authChannel]);

  const logout = () => {
    setIsLogged(false);
    setToken(null);
    setUser({});
    setEmail();
    sessionStorage.removeItem("email");
    sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
  };

  return (
    <p>
      {isLogged && (
        <>
          <p>
            <a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
          </p>
          <button onClick={() => logout()}>logout</button>
        </>
      )}
      {!isLogged && (
        <>
          <p>
            Please <a href="/login">login</a>
          </p>
        </>
      )}
    </p>
  );
};
```

*Login.js*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default (props) => {
  const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);
  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const authChannel = new BroadcastChannel("auth");

  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    email: "superadmin@a.com",
    password: "quantum"
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    authChannel.onmessage = function (e) {
      if (e.data.action === "logout") {
        setIsLogged(false);
        setToken();
        setUser({});
      }
    };
  }, [authChannel]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(sessionStorage.getItem("token"));
    setEmail(sessionStorage.getItem("email"));
    setIsLogged(sessionStorage.getItem("token") ? true : false);
  }, []);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    // handle login here...
    authChannel.postMessage({
      action: "login",
      target: "*",
      data: {
        user: { email: "a@a.com" },
        token: "kjdhlfjkgdjgdlfghjldhjgh76lgj"
      }
    });
    setIsLogged(true);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e, source) => {
    setInput({ ...input, [source]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {!isLogged && (
        <>
          <div>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={input.email || ""}
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, "email")}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              value={input.password || ""}
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, "password")}
            />
          </div>
          <button onClick={() => handleLogin()}>Login</button>
        </>
      )}
      {isLogged && <h1>You are logged now</h1>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Please do let me know what can be the reason for this.

Comment: I recommend you to add part of your code and the error you are getting.

Comment: If your are running your code in safari, BroadcastChannel doesn't work, here you can find some answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700474/how-can-i-use-the-broadcastchannel-api-or-something-similar-in-safari-10

Comment: @lissettdm I am using chrome and it is fine if I can get it working in Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are sending undefined data here:

Home.js

```
authChannel.postMessage({
  action: "login",
  target: e.data.source,
  data: { user: user, token: token } //--> user and token are undefined
});
```

Also I recommend you to change this line:

```
 const authChannel = new BroadcastChannel("auth");
```

Because every time the component is rendered, a new instance of `BroadcastChannel` is created. To avoid this you need to store the `BroadcastChannel` instance in `useRef`:

```
  const authChannelRef = useRef(new BroadcastChannel("auth"));
  const authChannel = authChannelRef.current;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and I will try as you said and update.